# What does the dialog fade out, then back in again?

Tags: jquery, css

My page shows images in my folder and allows deleting images by PHP. I want show an alert for deleting any image.

When you click on "No" in the alert it fade out then immediately fades back in again. Why is that happening?

In the example click to any image and click "No" in alert box to see my problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dele').each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newClass = "a" + i++;
    $this.addClass(newClass);
  });

  $('.alert').each(function(i) {
    var $jis = $(this);
    var jewClass = "b" + i++;
    $jis.addClass(jewClass);
    var hala = $jis.addClass(jewClass);
  });

  $(".dele").click(function() {
    $(this).children(".alert").fadeIn();
  });

  $("li.no, .alertclose").click(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #999;
}

div.alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1%;
  display: none;
  cursor: default;
}

div.note {
  width: 98%;
  padding: 1%;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14pt;
  line-height: 100%;
  direction: ltr;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul.yesorno {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center
}

ul.yesorno li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.yesorno li.no,
ul.yesorno li.inno {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  width: 50px;
  color: #999;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px
}

ul.yesorno li.yes a {
  background-color: #07BE03;
  width: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

div.dele {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dele">
  <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/yuqpe.xcnnr/v/vspfiles/photos/25-cent-E-liquid-Sample-2.jpg?1475251487">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="note">Are you sure?</div>
    <ul class="yesorno">
      <li class="yes"><a href="unlink.php?name='img1'">Yes</a></li>
      <li class="no">No</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dele">
  <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/yuqpe.xcnnr/v/vspfiles/photos/25-cent-E-liquid-Sample-2.jpg?1475251487">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="note">Are you sure?</div>
    <ul class="yesorno">
      <li class="yes"><a href="unlink.php?name='img2'">Yes</a></li>
      <li class="no">No</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dele">
  <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/yuqpe.xcnnr/v/vspfiles/photos/25-cent-E-liquid-Sample-2.jpg?1475251487">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="note">Are you sure?</div>
    <ul class="yesorno">
      <li class="yes"><a href="unlink.php?name='img3'">Yes</a></li>
      <li class="no">No</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dele">
  <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/yuqpe.xcnnr/v/vspfiles/photos/25-cent-E-liquid-Sample-2.jpg?1475251487">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="note">Are you sure?</div>
    <ul class="yesorno">
      <li class="yes"><a href="unlink.php?name='img4'">Yes</a></li>
      <li class="no">No</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `.no` elements are children of the `.dele` element. As such when you click `.no` the element fades out, however the click bubbles up the DOM to `.dele` which then fades it back in again.

To fix this issue, call `stopPropagation()` on the event in the `.no` click handler:

```
$("li.no, .alertclose").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".alert").fadeOut();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dele').each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newClass = "a" + i++;
    $this.addClass(newClass);
  });

  $('.alert').each(function(i) {
    var $jis = $(this);
    var jewClass = "b" + i++;
    $jis.addClass(jewClass);
    var hala = $jis.addClass(jewClass);
  });

  $(".dele").click(function() {
    $(this).children(".alert").fadeIn();
  });

  $("li.no, .alertclose").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".alert").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #999;
}

div.alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1%;
  display: none;
  cursor: default;
}

div.note {
  width: 98%;
  padding: 1%;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14pt;
  line-height: 100%;
  direction: ltr;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul.yesorno {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center
}

ul.yesorno li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.yesorno li.no,
ul.yesorno li.inno {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  width: 50px;
  color: #999;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px
}

ul.yesorno li.yes a {
  background-color: #07BE03;
  width: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

div.dele {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dele">
  <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/yuqpe.xcnnr/v/vspfiles/photos/25-cent-E-liquid-Sample-2.jpg?1475251487">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="note">Are you sure?</div>
    <ul class="yesorno">
      <li class="yes"><a href="unlink.php?name='img1'">Yes</a></li>
      <li class="no">No</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dele">
  <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/yuqpe.xcnnr/v/vspfiles/photos/25-cent-E-liquid-Sample-2.jpg?1475251487">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="note">Are you sure?</div>
    <ul class="yesorno">
      <li class="yes"><a href="unlink.php?name='img2'">Yes</a></li>
      <li class="no">No</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dele">
  <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/yuqpe.xcnnr/v/vspfiles/photos/25-cent-E-liquid-Sample-2.jpg?1475251487">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="note">Are you sure?</div>
    <ul class="yesorno">
      <li class="yes"><a href="unlink.php?name='img3'">Yes</a></li>
      <li class="no">No</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dele">
  <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/yuqpe.xcnnr/v/vspfiles/photos/25-cent-E-liquid-Sample-2.jpg?1475251487">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="note">Are you sure?</div>
    <ul class="yesorno">
      <li class="yes"><a href="unlink.php?name='img4'">Yes</a></li>
      <li class="no">No</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can u please replace your code with below.. tested and working for me

```
$('body').on('click','li.no, .alertclose',function() {
    $(".alert").fadeOut();
});
```